# Spring cloud Zuul url configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to run an example with zuul and Eureka server.

Below are my configurations:

```
eureka-service 

server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF

eureka -client (bootstrap.properties):

spring.application.name=ab
management.server.port=9001
management.server.address: 127.0.0.1
server.port=8081

edge-service(zuul) :

zuul.routes.ab.url=http://localhost:8081
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
spring.application.name=API-Gateway
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761
server.port=8080
```

While I am hitting the URL http:localhost:8080/clientapi, I get a white label error page, what configuration seems to be missing, as I could see edge-service, as well as eureka-client, registered correctly with the eureka -server.

I am using spring boot: 2.1.4.

Comment: What is in the logs of zuul? and eureka server (but you've turned it off)?

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you my example:

eureka in **application.yml** file:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: true
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
  server:
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 50000
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 5
```

zuul:

```
zuul.routes.1.url=http://localhost:8081
zuul.routes.2.url=http://localhost:8082

zuul.prefix=/client

zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=10
zuul.host.max-total-connections=10
```

I have 2 services (1 - localhost:8081 and 2 - localhost:8082)

You need annotate main class Zuul:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

Then start application. When you go to

```
localhost/8070/client/1
```

you will redirect to first service (localhost:8081)
When you go to

```
localhost/8070/client/2
```

I hope it will help you.

you will redirect to second service (localhost:8082)